# Valgrind does not work with WSL?

Tags: linux, windows, valgrind, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I installed `WSL` for my computer I was very excited to have a more natively supported `Linux` system rather than using `VirtualBox`. However I get this error when I try to run it. Is there a reason why?

I am happy to give more information as required.

```
--4364:0:aspacem   -1: ANON 0038000000-00383d5fff 4022272 r-x-- SmFixed d=0x000 i=25365   o=0       (0) m=0 /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux

--4364:0:aspacem  Valgrind: FATAL: aspacem assertion failed:

--4364:0:aspacem    segment_is_sane

--4364:0:aspacem    at m_aspacemgr/aspacemgr-linux.c:1502 (add_segment)

--4364:0:aspacem  Exiting now.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**It's definitely possible**

I've encountered some problems installing it directly with `apt`, however it can be installed manually with some very simple steps:

- **Download** the source file: `wget http://valgrind.org/downloads/valgrind-3.12.0.tar.bz2` (by the time you read this there could be a newer version)
- **Extract** the archive: `tar -xvjf valgrind-3.12.0.tar.bz2`
- **Configure** the installation process: `cd` into the exctracted folder `valgrind-3.12.0` and then launch `./configure`
- **Make**: simply launch `make` while in the `valgrind-3.12.0` folder
- **Check** the dependencies: launch `make check` to see whether all the dependencies necessary for the installation are satisfied (e.g: you'll have to install g++, just launch `sudo apt install g++`)
- **Install** *valgrind*: type `sudo make install` to install it

Comment: Great answer ! And you even posted it 30 minutes before I needed it. :)

Comment: Just "lunch" it? :D

Comment: +1 just got it running thanks for the answer. I only needed to change the download to `wget https://sourceware.org/pub/valgrind/valgrind-3.19.0.tar.bz2`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, the solution was to install Windows 10 creators update (version 1703), and reinstall Bash/WSL. Valgrind now works fine :)