# How to use Valgrind with WSL to profile a MSVC application on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, valgrind, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I would like to profile my application using Valgrind but I cannot find a tutorial on how to do it on Windows.

When I try to open my app with

```
valgrind -v ./ThreadClass.exe
```

i get

```
valgrind: ./ThreadClass.exe: cannot execute binary file
```

So the error is different than in those subjects:

'[Valgrind does not work with WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355474/valgrind-does-not-work-with-wsl)'

'[How to use Valgrind on Windows](http://www.albertgao.xyz/2016/09/28/how-to-use-valgrind-on-windows/)'

As it states in one of the answers in '[Valgrind does not work with WSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355474/valgrind-does-not-work-with-wsl)' it should work with the newest version of Windows 10 (creators update).

Can someone explain to me, how to profile an application with Valgrind on Windows 10?

Do I need to compile my application for linux to run it with Valgrind in WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valgrind in WSL only works with linux binaries, not windows ones. If you recompile your binary for linux, you should be able to run valgrind on that.