# How to use valgrind?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I am new to valgrind, using a windows system. But this pop up when I try to use it. What can I do?

[image: valgrind fail]

Comment: What's your distribution? Have you tried to install the recommend debug packages?

Comment: Have you read the part about "possible fixes"? All the output seems very Linux-specific. Are you sure you use a Windows program with it?

Comment: Better to include logs as text.

Comment: Recommend debug packages? Where can I find it?

Comment: I used window's subsystem linux.

Comment: logs? would you mind specify it more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Valgrind is not available for Windows. On their [home page](https://valgrind.org/), it says:

> It runs on the following platforms: X86/Linux, AMD64/Linux, ARM/Linux, ARM64/Linux, PPC32/Linux, PPC64/Linux, PPC64LE/Linux, S390X/Linux, MIPS32/Linux, MIPS64/Linux, X86/Solaris, AMD64/Solaris, ARM/Android (2.3.x and later), ARM64/Android, X86/Android (4.0 and later), MIPS32/Android, X86/Darwin and AMD64/Darwin (Mac OS X 10.12).

For alternatives, you can refer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows). Many people have listed other options.

**EDIT:**
Since you are using WSL, that does change things. (Next time, it would be good to add that sort of information to your question. Even if Valgrind worked on Windows, using WSL does change the answer.) You should know that valgrind will only work for Linux binaries then. You won't be able to use Visual Studio code.

Otherwise, it should technically be possible, but I've worked with WSL and since it's still in its early stages, things don't always work as you expect. It might just be in your case though, that you need to do the first possible fix by `sudo apt install libc6-dbg`.

If that doesn't work, [here is an answer about how to install it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43079470/11365539). No guarantees that this works though for you.

Comment: I followed a guideline to use the windows 's subsystem linux.

Comment: @ccnn edited my answer with updated information for WSL

Comment: thanks. problem fixed with "sudo apt install libc6-dbg".